# How can someone find the source of the noise invading the car interior?

Tags: noise, interior

Suppose hypothetically that the interior of a car has a hole, a vent, or any kind of "sound leakage" that lets the exterior, wind and/or engine noise pass from the exterior to the interior of the cabin. And, most importantly, you don't know where the source of this "sound leakage" is. How would you be able to find the source? What kind of tools and equipment could be used to make this task easier and how they should be used for this specific situation?

Comment: I would get the help of another person to sit in different seats and try to find it. You would need the help of another anyway, if you are driving.

Comment: You listen to the noise to identify things like frequency ie engine peed or wheel speed etc

Comment: A stethoscope, a kind of hose that you place against your ear, and the other end against the area you suspect is producing noise. If you place the open end against different places, the sound would be louder near the source of the noise. Simple and effective. Can even use a piece of plastic tubing to lesser effect.